# bcrypt.hash()'s next() call is not triggering the mongoose save method

Tags: typescript, mongoose, bcrypt

I'm trying to hash a password with the following `.pre()` hook:

```
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt'; // "bcrypt": "^1.0.2"
(<any>mongoose).Promise = require('bluebird');


const user_schema = new Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
})

const SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;

user_schema.pre('save', function (next) {
  const user = this;
  if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();
  bcrypt.hash(user.password, SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function (error, hash) {
    if (error) return next(error);
    user.password = hash;
    console.log(hash); // properly consoles the hash
    next();
  });
});
```

as I have noted above, the hash value properly consoles, so it is being made properly. however, when I save like this:

```
const x = new MongoUser({
  '_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
  'email': 'test@test.com',
  'password': 'testp@$$word',
})
console.log(x); // this consoles the object properly
x.save(function(err: any){
  console.log('callback fired'); // this does not
  if (err) console.log(err)
});
```

I find that the `save()` callback is never called.

I can execute the `save()` with an unhashed password by removing the `.pre90` hook or by replacing the `bcrypt.hash()` with a `next()` call the user is save with an unhashed password, so I'm confident about the schema implementation and db connection.

**Why is the `save()` not getting triggered?**

This isn't a race issue either because I `tcs` the files and then run a separate execution script

Comment: I'm not sure if you have already resolved this issue. It may have something to do with the mongoose/nodejs/bcrypt version you are using. It works as expected with `bcrypt 1.0.2,
    mongoose 4.8.6` and `node js v7.2.0`.

Comment: I've updated to the newest versions and it still isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing some steps. The code below works for me. I have tested this on bcrypt 1.0.2, mongoose 4.8.6 and node js v7.2.0

```
import * as bcrypt from 'bcrypt'; 
import * as mongoose from 'mongoose'; 

const user_schema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: { type: String, required: true },
  password: { type: String, required: true },
})

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', function(err,db){
    if (!err){
        console.log('Connected to /localhost!');
    } else{
        console.dir(err);
    }
});

const SALT_WORK_FACTOR = 10;

user_schema.pre('save', function (next) {
  const user = this;
  if (!user.isModified('password')) return next();
  bcrypt.hash(user.password, SALT_WORK_FACTOR, function (error, hash) {
    if (error) return next(error);
    user.password = hash;
    console.log(hash); // properly consoles the hash
    next();
  });
});

var MongoUser = mongoose.model('collectionName', user_schema);

const x = new MongoUser({
  '_id': mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
  'email': 'test@test.com',
  'password': 'testp@$$word',
})
console.log(x); // this consoles the object properly
x.save(function(err: any){
  console.log('callback fired'); // this does not
  if (err) console.log(err)
});
```

Here is my document.

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58c7360e976e543af0667039"), "email" : "test@test.com", "password" : "$2a$10$h06qq1mhTCzlP5rN6.nEW.DZSlsXzU5gsAK/lShi7NOtvG6qEvqSa", "__v" : 0 }
```

Console logs:

```
{ _id: 58c7360e976e543af0667039,
  email: 'test@test.com',
  password: 'testp@$$word' }
(node:15088) DeprecationWarning: Mongoose: mpromise (mongoose's default pro
Connected to /localhost!
$2a$10$h06qq1mhTCzlP5rN6.nEW.DZSlsXzU5gsAK/lShi7NOtvG6qEvqSa
callback fired
```

Comment: I was missing some server setup steps. I'm not exactly sure what although it's working now.